# Performance profiling on a remote PC

Tags: c++, mfc, performance-testing, remote-debugging

I have a 64 bit C++ MFC application developed in VS2015 that normally performs well, but has started to run very slowly on some client Windows 10 PCs.  Is it possible to carry out a remote performance profiling session to get to the root of this issue without having to install all of VS2015 on the remote PC?  I suspect the issue relates to a Windows update, as the issue occurs primarily on startup, but would like to get some more in-depth analysis.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Windows Performance Toolkit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/test/wpt/index), which includes the [Windows Performance Recorder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/test/wpt/windows-performance-recorder) (to be installed & run on the remote machine) and the [Windows Performance Analyzer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/test/wpt/windows-performance-analyzer), a tool that creates graphs and data tables of Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) events that are recorded by Windows Performance Recorder.

Comment: Is it possible to do performance profiling in realtime?

Comment: @Dominique I don't understand what you mean by realtime.